# SQL Get max value of n next rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Say I have a table with two columns: the time and the value. I want to be able to get a table with :
for each time get the max values of every next n seconds.

If I want the max value of every next 3 seconds, the following table:

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 7 |

Should return:

| time | value | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | 3 | NULL |
| 9 | 7 | NULL |

Is there a way to do this directly with an sql query?

Comment: How do you get those values in max column? IOW why 1, max is 6 and for 3,4,5 it is 5? It is not clear.

Comment: Why is time 1 6 shouldn't it be 4 if it's the "NEXT" three seconds, that would be exclusive of time 1...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `max` window function:

```
select *,
case 
when row_number() over(order by time desc) > 2 then
max(value) over(order by time rows between current row and 2 following)
end as max
from table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cdc9ee68e85a553eb921ec40755a36bc)

The case expression checks that there are more than 2 rows after the current row to calculate the max, otherwise `null` is returned (for the last 2 rows ordered by time).

Answer (score 0):

Similar Version to Zakaria, but this solution uses about 40% less CPU resources (scaled to 3M rows for benchmark) as the window functions both use the same exact OVER clause so SQL can better optimize the query.

### Optimized Max Value of Rolling Window of 3 Rows

```
SELECT *,
    MaxValueIn3SecondWindow =   CASE 
                                    /*Check 3 rows exists to compare. If 3 rows exists, then calculate max value*/
                                    WHEN 3 =   COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
                                    /*Returns max [Value] between the current row and the next 2 rows*/
                                    THEN MAX(A.[Value]) OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING)
                                END
FROM #YourTable AS A
```